# Can't delete cookie from ad server in JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

Cannot delete cookie using JavaScript. The cookie is being set by a third party on my domain. I'm using the following JavaScript where 'cookieName' is the name of the cookie and the 'path' and 'hostname' are the same as the cookie in question (hostname is my domain - location.hostname). 
The following happily deletes cookies set by me, but doesn't touch the ad cookie.

```
document.cookie = cookieName +'=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path='+ path +'; domain='+ hostname +';'
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is the HttpOnly flag enabled? If so, you can’t access it from JS – see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: My thoughts exactly. That, or the cookie is being set later (which for ad cookies is usually the case, as those usually depend on various requests to ad networks).

Comment: No, the HttpOnly flag is not added, it is; HostOnly Y, secure N, session N, HttpOnly N

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it turns out to be simple confusion. If you are having the same issue, try omitting the domain declaration altogether, this worked for me. Writing out the cookie in JavaScript shows the domain as "www.mydomain.co.uk" but setting it to domain=www.mydomain.co.uk; will fail. Omitting the domain declaration entirely worked in this use case.  (As the cookie gets recreated all the time I haven't bother to expire it.)

```
document.cookie = cookieName +'=; path='+ path +';';
```

The above empties the cookie, which stops it growing too large and breaking other stuff.